# Arvore binária imprimindo apenas o lado esquerdo

Tags: c, c++, estrutura-de-dados, árvore-binária

Olá.
Minha arvore binária está imprimindo apenas o lado esquerdo, o que pode ser? Estou utilizando TAD para implementar.

Estrutura da arvore:

```
typedef struct _no {
    int conteudo;
    struct _no *esquerda;
    struct _no *direita;
    struct _no *pai;
} Arvore;
```

Função inserção.

```
void inserir(Arvore **arv, int numero){
    Arvore *aux, *ant;
    aux = *arv;

    Arvore *novo;
    novo = (Arvore*) malloc(sizeof(Arvore));
    novo->direita = NULL;
    novo->esquerda = NULL;
    novo->conteudo = numero;

    if(estaVazia(*arv)){
        novo->pai = NULL;
        *arv = novo;
        return;
     }

    while (aux != NULL){
        ant = aux;

        if(numero > aux->conteudo){
            aux = aux->direita;
         }else{
            aux = aux->esquerda;
         }
     }

     if (numero > ant->conteudo){
        ant->direita = novo;
        novo->pai = aux;


     }else{
        ant->esquerda = novo;
        novo->pai = aux;

     }

     free(aux);
}
```

Função de impressão

```
void preOrdem(Arvore *arv){

    printf("%d ", arv->conteudo);
    preOrdem(arv->esquerda);
    preOrdem(arv->direita);


}
```

Arquivo principal

```
int main(){

    Arvore *arvore;

    inicializarArvore(&arvore);
    inserir(&arvore,20);
    inserir(&arvore,25);
    inserir(&arvore,10);
    inserir(&arvore,5);
    inserir(&arvore,30);

    preOrdem(arvore);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olhando só para a função imprime e assumindo que as outras funções estão bem implementadas dá para reparar que não dá `return` na função do imprime.

```
void preOrdem(Arvore *arv){
    if(arv==NULL)
       return;

    printf("%d ", arv->conteudo);
    preOrdem(arv->esquerda);
    preOrdem(arv->direita);
}
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pela sua função ficava naquele nó, quando for chamada outra vez a função para o `arv->esquerda` vai para um nó nulo e vai fechar o programa.

É preciso haver o `return` para ela voltar ao numero `7` e ir para a `direita`

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado.

Comment: Recursividade em árvores é um assunto complicado, é preciso saber muito bem o que faz cada coisa. Há videos muito bons no youtube que ensina passo a passo o que faz cada linha de codigo.